# Default random engine and static cast

Tags: c++

The class `default_random_engine` is very useful for producing random numbers, but some programmers use `template function static_cast` for the constructor of the object defined with this class:

```
default_random_engine myEngine(static_cast<unsigned int>time(0));
```

However, I cannot understand the reason of this usage format above.
I have used this usage format below up to now:

```
default_random_engine myEngine(time(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `time_t` (the return of `time`) is not specified in the C++ standard and hence is implementation dependent. If the actual type of `time_t` is not terribly compatible with the type expected by the `default_random_engine` constructor then a compilation warning is likely. The cast is probably there to get past that.

Comment: Yup. It's required to be an **arithmetic type**, so there's no real incompatibility. The **only** reason for that cast is to quiet a warning.